# Do people who download apk from beta channel have to install it again when it is in production?

Tags: google-play-console

Basically I have my first app in beta channel some people download it but I have the doubt if when i launch in production channel those people have to uninstall the beta's apk and install the new one or is a different process to do that?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you promote the APK from beta to production, then they won't have to download it again since it's the same APK (with the same versionCode).

If you upload a new APK with a higher versionCode on the production track, then yes, they would receive an update.

Comment: Thanks for the answer